# How do I make client-side changes from 3rd party calling server-side function?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js/express application and am interfacing to a 3rd ePayment provider (www.eway.com.au). The user hits my 'Pay' button, which via ajax calls a server-side function to retrieve order/client data then opens-up a new window to display eWay hosted payment screen. The user then adds credit-card details, and eWay processes the payment and calls one of my server-side functions to return confirmation data and I store that info in my application. All good so far.

I send this json snippet to eWay:

```
"RedirectUrl": "http://127.0.0.1/payReturn",
```

And here is my express:

```
app.get('payReturn?:acode', mscr.payReturn);
```

The problem is that once eWay calls my server-side RedirectUrl to return their data, I need to then make client-side html changes to reflect that change.

So how do I make client-side html changes from a server-side function which was not initiated from the client? (it was called from 3rd party - eWay)

Answer (score 0):

The answer in such cases is "long polling" or some sort of push technology.

In the first case the initial page calls an Ajax endpoint on a timer that checks for a value that is set when the payment processor calls back your app.

In the second, you'd use something like a web socket to inform the client that the callback has happened.